# Run source control in visual studio

Tags: c#, tfs

Is it possible to run a source control on a team project in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Yes you can use various Source Code Version Control Software...

Comment: can you explain more ? thanks

Comment: http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/versioncontrol.shtml Read this

Comment: What do mean with 'by the time'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both TFS and VSO provide the same capabilities for developers working together to build a single product.

https://www.visualstudio.com/features/version-control-vs

You would be best using Git if you are just starting out, or TFVC if you already have a large legacy codebase.

You would also be best using VSO (TFS Online) as it is much easier to setup and support.